# How can I change MPI error handler before MPI_init?

Tags: fortran, mpi, intel-fortran

I have a Fortran code which is predominantly used for running large MPI calculations, but occasionally I want to run it on a machine which does not have MPI available for quick data processing tasks.

I have a logical variable which determines whether or not the program is being run in MPI mode or not, and when it is false the code will not call any MPI subroutines. The way I determine whether or not to run in MPI mode at the moment is by testing to see if a dummy file "NO_MPI" exists which I dislike due to its inelegance and the fact that I usually forget that I need to create this file when running in a non-MPI environment.

When the code is run in a non-MPI environment the `MPI_init` subroutine will fail and cause the program to crash. So what I would like to do is call it with the optional error output:

`call MPI_init(ierr)`

and then if an error is returned continue with the node in non-MPI mode.

The issue is that the default MPI error handler will abort the program without returning an error. For any other MPI subroutine the solution would be:

`call MPI_Comm_set_errhandler(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_ERRORS_RETURN)`

to tell MPI not to abort and return the error code. However I cannot call this subroutine before `MPI_init` without getting the error
`Attempting to use an MPI routine before initializing MPICH`.

Is there any way to change the default error handler before calling `MPI_init`, perhaps specifying it with a compiler flag? I am using the IFORT compiler with MPICH.

I feel that there must be some way of testing the error code from `MPI_init`, otherwise what is the point of allowing `MPI_init` to accept the optional error return as an argument when the default behaviour is to abort without returning errors?

Comment: sorry, you cannot.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any insight on how the error return for the MPI_init subroutine should be used then? Or is it just that all MPI subroutines having the optional error return and in the case of MPI_init it is useless?

Comment: If your implementation decides to abort instead of returning an error code, then you are basically stuck with it. This is not the first time this question is asked, so feel free to ask the MPI forum if there is (plan for) a portable solution https://lists.mpi-forum.org/mailman/listinfo/mpi-comments

Comment: So this is super hacky, and completely non-portable. You could run `mpiexec -n 1 /usr/bin/env` and pick one of the environment variables that gets set by MPICH at run time. Then test for that environment variable (`call GET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE`) prior to calling `MPI_Init`.

Again, this is in no way portable, but if you have a *very* stable environment it would let you know whether or not you are running in an MPI environment.

Comment: Can I ask when you say "does not have MPI available" how are you linking the code if you are still calling MPI_Init?

Comment: @IanBush Yes I was unclear about that, the machine still has the MPI libraries for compiling the code, the issue is when I am running the program on a login node which cannot start an MPI task rather than on a compute node where the MPI programs should be run. So in this case the MPI_init function can be called but it aborts the program and prints an error to screen.

Comment: So to be absolutely clear on the login node you have no access to mpirun/mpiexec/similar, or alternatively the mpi job launcher is restricted so that something like mpirun -np 1 ./my_executable does not work?

Comment: @IanBush Yes, attempting to use mpirun on a login node will just result in the job being schedule to run on a compute node.

Comment: @Dr.Tower Thank you, that is indeed quite hacky but it will solve my problem just fine. I found a bunch of environment variables which are only present on the machine where I am able to run MPI.

Comment: OK - trying to get it to run on the localhost instead with something like mpiexec -host (https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www1/mpiexec.html) might get you somewhere, but otherwise as mentioned above I think you are going to have to look at something specific to your set up

Comment: How exactly is your code failing? The MPI standard demands support for something called "singleton MPI_INIT". Basically, when you run your executable without `mpiexec`, it should behave as if `mpiexec -n 1 ...` was used instead. As long as your code is written in such a way as to run with just 1 MPI rank, you don't need any special mechanism to distinguish the cases.

Comment: @HristoIliev when I try to run the program on a login node I get the error:
`Fatal error in MPI_Init: Other MPI error` along with `MPID_Init(246).......: channel initialization failed`. I am by no means an expert but since the login nodes on this machine are not supposed to be used for MPI jobs I has always assumed they were just set up in such a way that MPI tasks could not be initialised.

Comment: Does it work when running the executable directly without `mpiexec`/`mpirun`?